# Moderator Elections?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know how often moderator elections are held on this site? Or more importantly, when the next one would be?

I would like to throw my hat into the ring for election as moderator so that certain issues can be dealt with a little faster than is currently the norm (not a criticism, everyone is busy, it's just that I am here pretty much every working day and the current mods often aren't).

I have read [this excellent question](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/does-pmse-have-a-process-for-adding-community-moderators)  from CodeGnome and the answer provided by Jmort253 appears to rest on the tiered moderator privileges that come as part of an SE site. However, with the slowdown in rep on the site it is difficult to advance moderation privileges quickly enough and one or more new diamond moderators that are more regular users of the site would be able to assist with cleaning duties in a more timely fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that SE doesn't hold moderator elections on beta sites. I think PMSE is an edge case, because we're a fairly well-viewed site with a lot of participation, but we currently don't have the [volume of questions](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management) (pegged at 10 per day) to graduate from beta.

I'm not against having community moderator elections to supplement the diamond moderators, but I'm not sure what the process is to request an exception. Maybe someone else knows, and will chime in.